# Filtrar um array de datas pelo equivalente numero do mes e o ano Javascript

Tags: javascript

## Problema

Preciso filtrar um array de datas string

exemplo:

```
data = [[user1, 20/11/2019], [user1, 25/05/2019], [user1, 27/11/2019]]
```

Onde o usuário seleciona o nome o mês "11" e o ano "2019", no caso o retorno seria:

```
"20/11/2019", "27/11/2019"
```

## Código

```
var funcionarioId ="user1"
var month = "11"
var year = "2019";

var dataFiltered = data.filter(function(item){return item[1] === funcionarioId && 
 item[3] === month && 
 item[3] === year });
```

Acredito ter que encontrar as posições em que se encontram o mês e ano e aplicar o filtro.

Comment: Esta e a estrutura copiada diretamente do meu console.log()  [[1, 134, DIOGO, 03/12/2019, first, 2, 28/11/2019 09:43:23], [2, 131, ALEISIO, 13/11/2019, second, 33, 28/11/2019 09:49:57], [3, 134, DIOGO, 25/11/2019, third, 2, 28/11/2019 09:43:23], [4, 134, DIOGO, 15/12/2019, fourth, 2, 28/11/2019 09:43:23]]

Answer (score 0):

O codigo abaixo resolvel a minha situacao. Obrigado a todos pela paciencia.

```
var funcionarioId = '134';
var month = "11"
var year = "2019";

var filteredData = data.filter(function(item) {
var dataSplit = item[3].split('/');
return dataSplit[1] === month &&
       dataSplit[2] === year &&
       item[1] == funcionarioId
});
```